# Two Block Pulley Emergency

Tags: acceleration

[image: ProblemImage]

So I took AP Physics last year, and am taking a more advanced AP Physics course this year. However my teacher from last year solves the following problem with one method and my current teacher solves it with a different method. The problem is both methods disagree, and I cannot decern which is flawed and why. Can somebody please help me understand which of these two methods is correct and why the other method is flawed?

Method one:

[image: MethodOne]

You can view both blocks as a system shown in the above image.

Fn=ma --> Fn=m2g --> m2g=(m1+m2)a --> a=m2g/(m1+m2)

This seems to be how the collegeboard does it.

Method two:

[image: MethodTwo]

You set up a system of equations based on the above image.

Fn=ma --> Fn=Ft --> Ft=ma --> Ft=(m1+m2)a

Fn=ma --> Fg-Ft=Fn --> Fg=m2g --> Fg-Ft=ma --> m2g-Ft=(m1+m2)a

Substitute: m2g-(m1+m2)a=(m1+m2)a --> m2g=2(m1+m2)a --> a=m2g/2(m1+m2)

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Why is the word "emergency" in the title? It has nothing to do with the question. Please read our [FAQ about titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles). Also please read the help center to learn how to use proper math formatting on this site.

Comment: Done with correct algebra method two (which arises from a completely general algorithm) give the same answer as method one (which relies on an intuitive understanding of the problem to shorten the work). Method two is also able to cope with massive pulleys and the introduction of friction in the problem. It is much more important that u=you understand how to do method two *correctly* than learning method one which is a special case.

Answer (score 3):

In method two,you are writing $F_{net}=ma$ separately for each block.So it should be $F_t=m_1a$ and $m_2g-F_t=m_2a$,that is,you must use the mass of just the one block you are considering,not both the blocks together.This agrees with method 1,which is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Method #1 is correct. Not exactly sure what's going on with the attempted solution in Method #2, but one thing to try in situations like this is to try out some special cases to see if the answer makes sense. For example, let's take the special case where the mass m1 is zero. It should be apparent that the acceleration in this special case should simply be 'g', and that's what the equation from Method #1 gives if you set m1=0 in it. But if you set m1=0 in the equation from Method #1, then you get a=g/2, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Method #1 *is* correct.